# What is the largest n for n!< 1000?

Tags: factorial

This is simple factorial equation question.

How do you find the largest n satisfying n! < 1000?

(Edit)

Actually, I want to find some other logic other than brute force.

For example,

How about the largest n for $n!<10^{64}$?

Comment: Well, did you try computing $5!,6!,7!$?

Comment: I want to find a logical steps to find the n, other than brute force way.

Comment: @Hanasima, you are on the right path. only if there was an inverse factorial or inverse $\Gamma$ function this question would have been easy.

Comment: @Hanasima Well, $n!>2^n$ if $n>4$, and $2^{10}=1024$, so you can look at $n=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9$. Is that good enough? It isn't really brute forcing. One the other hand $6!=720$ so clearly...? Have you never computed a Taylor series up to the $6$th term? :)

Comment: @Hanasima: The brute force way is plenty logical. No sense trying to make an easy problem hard!

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/171882/is-there-a-way-to-reverse-factorials?rq=1

Comment: @PedroTamaroff, thanks, and I think I should reiterate the question. That is not what I want.

Comment: The largest $n$ so that $n! < 10^{64}$ is also relatively easy by brute force. What is it that you are *actually* trying to do that you want this? If you could explain that, then people could give you responses that could help you do what you're *actually* trying to do. (which may include explaining why the approach you've taken is not the best way to go about it)

Comment: @Hanasima : I think what you are really interested in is the stirlings approximation for the $\Gamma$ function, the factorial and $\Gamma$ function are pretty mush the same for $n\geq 0$

Comment: @Hurkyl, what I want is to find the largest n for n!<k, k is very large number, which is not easy to get by brute force way.

Comment: @Arjang, yeah, probably. So, I'm reading the wiki how I can use it.

Comment: @Hanasima: $10^{64}$ is nowhere near the point where the problem has gone beyond "easy to get by brute force way". e.g. just about the simplest python program to do this completes in 0.05 seconds.

Answer (score 6):

If you are looking for non brute force methods of dealing with factorials, then probably what you want is Stirling's approximation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation

However, this approximation is really only helpful for large $n$; in your case, I'd say brute force is the best option.

Personally, I recall that $5! = 120$, after which $6! = 720$, and you know $7! > 1000$.

---

**In response to the edit:** To consider when $n!$ exceeds $10^{64}$ is to consider when $n!$ has at least sixty four digits; this sort of question can be broached using Stirling's Approximation combined with a base-$10$ log. Probably you could work this out yourself, but for more details, see [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20180209014208/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/68245.html).

Comment: Thanks. Now, I'm looking how to use the approximation to solve the original example.

Comment: @Hanasima: Okay, I have added additional details for your subsequent edit.

Answer (score 3):

There is a table of the first factorials
at http://www.tsm-resources.com/alists/fact.html
that can help you.

Comment: that is the same as brute force, isn't there an inverse factorial function somewhere?

Comment: @Arjang That table *is* the "inverse factorial function" (for natural numbers at least).

Comment: You can get good approximations by inverting Stirling's theorem, but there will always be problems near a large factorial $\pm 1$.

Comment: Thanks for the link. It would be helpful to find n for upto a certain number.

Answer (score 0):

50! = 3.0414 x 10^64
Factorials are defined for positive integers. Stirling's formula happens to give excellent results for factorials (n=positive integer).  But it also works for positive non-integers.  However, non-integers aren't factorials.  It's interesting that 0! is defined as being equal to 1.  This is necessary for calculating probabilities.

Greg Schaffer

Comment: The quality of this answer is diluted by irrelevant matter.