# Rewriting Factorial Expressions

Tags: elementary-number-theory, factorial

If I have an equation, say,
$$
y = x! +1
$$
Is it possible to rewrite the equation in terms of $x$?

For example, a simple algebraic equation might be $y = x^2$ --- and to rewrite it in terms of $x$, one might say $x = \sqrt{y}$.

I don't mind if the function isn't continuous, but I am curious as to whether or not this is possible...
Thank you very much!

Comment: Here's a similar question.  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/171882/is-there-a-way-to-reverse-factorials