# What is the reverse operation of a factorial?

Tags: functions, factorial

Is there a mathematical function $f$ that takes $n!$ as an input, and returns $n$?

For example,

$f(720) = 6$

Comment: Perhaps it is $n¡$? Joking aside, I doubt this function has an actual name and applications, because it's domain is very very restricted.

Comment: Also [related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/171882/is-there-a-way-to-reverse-factorials?rq=1)

Comment: My mistake, I didn't notice it was a duplicate.

Comment: I don't know if the function has a name but it obviously exists as you just described it.  You can extend it by taking the inverse of the Gamma function (minus one, where $\Gamma $ is invertible).