# Opposite of Factorial?

Tags: factorial

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to solve for an unknown in a factorial?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61755/is-there-a-way-to-solve-for-an-unknown-in-a-factorial)

I was just wondering, what would be the opposite of factorial?

For example, If I had $n! = 120$. How can I then show algebraically that $n = 5$?

Comment: You could repeatedly divide your number by increasing integers; and if at any point you divide by $k$ and are left with $k+1$ then you know that the number you started with is $(k+1)!$.

Comment: Are you looking for a solution that works when the result is a non-integer? For example, suppose someone asks you for $n$ such that $n! = 200$.  Do you want to say "There is no such $n$," or do you want to say "$n$ would have to be between 5 and 6", or do you want to say "$n\approx 5.297$"?

Comment: @MJD If possible, I would like to know both methods.

Comment: [Relevant](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/12828/inverse-gamma-function)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*[Added because of a question in a comment]* The generalization of the factorial is the gamma-function: $n! = \Gamma(1+n) $ where we can also insert noninteger values for n: $y = \Gamma(z) $ such that we have a function over the complex numbers $z$ except the poles at the non-positive integers).*[/added]*

The gamma-function has two real fixpoints. If you write the power-series of the gamma around one of that fixpoints, then this power series has no constant term and can be reverted by series-reversion. From this you can then get the inverse of the gamma, and from this the inverse of the factorial. Unfortunately, the convergence-radii of that series are both small, so I cant say at the moment, how useful this process would actually be.

*(I think I've seen a question concerning the inverse of the gamma here or on MO, and possibly even showed a couple of that coefficients: see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18362/is-there-an-inverse-gamma-gamma-1-z-function) for a short discussion)*

Comment: I don't know what the gamma function is.. Can you please offer an explanation to what this means?

Comment: @gekkostate:  you could start at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) or [Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GammaFunction.html)

Comment: @gekkostate:  you can also numerically invert [Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sterling%27s_approximation) that $\ln n! \approx n \ln n -n +\frac 12\ln(2\pi n)$ to get intermediate values

Comment: You are probably referring to this thread: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/12828/inverse-gamma-function