# How to solve a factorial using the Stirling Approximation?

Tags: approximation, factorial, wolfram-alpha

I'm working on a problem where I need to solve for b in terms of a and z, given $z = (a + b)!$. An approximate solution using the Stirling Approximation: $z = \sqrt {2\pi (a + b)}\left(\frac {(a + b)}{e}\right)^{(a + b)}$would suffice but I'm having trouble with the algebra and Wolfram seems to run out of compute time before generating a solution for me.

Answer (score 2):

A solution is $b=\Gamma^{-1}(z)-a-1$ with the (functional) inverse of the Gamma function. If this looks like cheating or you have no access to the $\Gamma^{-1},$ you have to solve it numerically, e.g. with Newton's method. The (incomplete) inverse Gamma function is used e.g. in statistics.

For a numerical approximation see [Is there an Inverse Gamma $\Gamma^{-1} (z) $ function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18362/is-there-an-inverse-gamma-gamma-1-z-function) ,
for an approximation of $\Gamma^{-1}$ in terms of [LambertW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambertw) see
https://mathoverflow.net/a/28977